# Creating a view for summary

Tags: sql, database

I have a table of questions. The questions can be high priority, low priority, open/answered. What is the best way to create a summary. Should I use a view or several stored procedures?

Table example:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[question] (
    [Id]            INT          NOT NULL,
    [Priority]      INT          NOT NULL,
    [State]         INT          NOT NULL)
```

I think creating a view with 4 columns is the best: OpenQuestionHighPriority, OpenQuestionLowPriority, ClosedQuestionHighPriority,ClosedQuestionLowPriority.

Like to know how to do this or other suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could query that with a `case`:

```
select  sum(case when priority = 1 and state = 1 then 1 end) 
            as OpenQuestionHighPriority
,       sum(case when priority = 1 and state = 2 then 1 end) 
            as ClosedQuestionHighPriority
....
from    dbo.question
```

You could store this query in a view, a procedure, or execute it as ad-hoc SQL.  It will work in either form.

Comment: Awesome! It runs good. One question, what is the last "1" stand for? True?

Comment: @Icerman: Your `state` and `priority` columns are integers.  I'm not sure what they mean, but I was guessing 1 meant Open, and 2 meant Closed.  If that's correct, it's just a lucky guess.

Comment: Ohh, yes. But my question is on the "1" after "then".

Comment: @Icerman: Aah, that's to make every row count as `1` for the `sum`.  If you'd replace it by `2`, you'd end up with `DoubleOpenQuestionHighPriority` :)

Comment: Is there a way to set OpenQuestionHighPriority default to 0. The problem (return NULL) arise when there is nothing in question table.

Comment: @Iceman: Sure, wrap it with `isnull` like `isnull(sum(case ... end), 0) as OpenQUestionHighPriority`